# Jenkins can not execute docker login via ssh-agent

Tags: docker, jenkins, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecr

I create the Jenkins pipeline to deploy my app. I built and push docker image to AWS ECR. The final step is executing ssh to deployment server (EC2) and run docker container based on last built image.

This is my script:

```
stage('Deploy') {
            steps {
                script {
                    sshagent(['ssh-cridentials']) {
                        sh "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no jenkins@host sudo docker rm -f myapp"
                        sh "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no jenkins@host sudo docker image prune -a -f"
                        sh "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no jenkins@host \"cat /opt/aws/password.txt | sudo docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $ecrURI & sudo docker run -p 80:80 -d --name=myapp $imageURI\""
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

However, Jenkins built fail and I got the error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: Get https://xxx: no basic auth credentials.
```

This command couldn't login to ECR. 
But it works successfully if I execute the same command on deployment server.

Comment: Does your password has special characters?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like something wrong with your escape character, try without using that (I believe you have valid ecr url in variable $ecrURI)

```
sh "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no jenkins@host cat /opt/aws/password.txt | sudo docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $ecrURI & sudo docker run -p 80:80 -d --name=myapp $imageURI"
```